The session cookie cannot be unprotected when ASP.NET Core 8.0 Web App runs on IIS
Once the below configuration is added to Startup.cs of an ASP.NET Core MVC Web Application targeting .NET 8.0:
services.AddSession(options =>
{
    options.IdleTimeout = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(50);
    options.Cookie.IsEssential = true;
    options.Cookie.HttpOnly = true;                
    options.Cookie.SameSite = SameSiteMode.Strict;
});

...

app.UseSession();

hundreds such warnings are logged by the application deployed to an IIS 8.5 server (Windows Server 2012 R2):

https://example.com/Login: Error unprotecting the session cookie.
Logger: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Session.SessionMiddleware
Callsite: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Session.CookieProtection.Unprotect
Exception: System.Security.Cryptography.CryptographicException: The
key  {x-y-z} was not found in the key ring.  For more information go
to https://aka.ms/aspnet/dataprotectionwarning at
Microsoft.AspNetCore.DataProtection.KeyManagement.KeyRingBasedDataProtector.UnprotectCore(Byte[]
protectedData, Boolean allowOperationsOnRevokedKeys, UnprotectStatus&
status) at
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Session.CookieProtection.Unprotect(IDataProtector
protector, String  protectedText, ILogger logger)

Session is only used to store a list of announcements to show to the user once he logs in:
[HttpPost]
public async Task<IActionResult> Login(...)
{
   ...
   await announcementService.BuildAnnouncementsFor(user);
   ...
}

Ultimately, BuildAnnoucementsFor stores a list of announcements (i.e. strings) to session using IHttpContextAccessor.HttpContext.Session, which is configured as following:
services.AddHttpContextAccessor();

services.AddSingleton<IHttpContextAccessor, HttpContextAccessor>();

I've already configured User Profile to be loaded in IIS configuration since DataProtection seems to be related to the problem and when the application pool was (re)started the bellow warning was also logged:

Neither user profile nor HKLM registry available. Using an ephemeral
key repository.  Protected data will be unavailable when application
exits.

The above had the latter warning go away but SessionMiddleware still warns about the encryption key not found in the key ring. Indeed, the keys reported in the warnings are not in the C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\Crypto\RSA\MachineKeys folder, where IIS looks for keys, by default.
I would very much like to have those warnings go away but I don't know what else needs to be configured either in code or in IIS.

Try setting a Custom Identity on the App Pool (a regular user), and set "Load User Profile" to true

It seems your problem is related to Data Protection Configuration https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/data-protection/configuration/overview?view=aspnetcore-8.0

Does same error occur with Core 7?  Core 8 is still buggy.

@JesúsLópez As said, I've already configured the app pool to no avail. Also, none of the non-default DataProtection configurations seems to fit my case: a simple web app running on a single iis server; no azure, no farm.

Can I understand the question as, we added session mechanism into the asp.net core application, it worked well locally, but it has exception after deploying to IIS 8.5 in win server 2012?

@TinyWang exactly.

@jdweng Unfortunately, I cannot confirm that.

See following : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40865011/error-unprotecting-the-session-cookie-exception

@jdweng Hm, this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/71924040/313935 looks interesting even though that thread is specific to authentication (and that's why I had skipped it in the first place). Nevertheless, I'll try to give a custom name to the Session cookie and get back to you.

@jdweng https://stackoverflow.com/a/71924040/313935 probably did the trick. Need to test it a bit further but seems to be resolved now. Thanks.

After having applied various configuration combinations and testing I think I should answer my own question.
To have Session cookie work properly for an ASP.NET Core 8 MVC Web Application hosted in IIS 8.5 on Windows Server 20212 R2, make sure:

"Load User Profile" property is set to true in IIS Configuration. How to configure it is described in this answer.
The Session cookie has a unique name to avoid conflict with the rest Web Applications hosted on the same server, which is a safe assumption. How to configure it is described in this answer but let me also mention it here for brevity:

services.AddSession(options => {
  ...
  options.Cookie.Name = ".yourApp.Session";
  ...
});

Hope it helps.
